# Where can I view service account created by `eksctl`?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-eks

I create a EKS cluster in AWS and use this command to create a service account `eksctl create iamserviceaccount --name alb-ingress-controller --cluster $componentName --attach-policy-arn $serviceRoleArn --approve --override-existing-serviceaccounts`.
The output of the command is:

```
[ℹ]  using region ap-southeast-2
[ℹ]  1 existing iamserviceaccount(s) (default/alb-ingress-controller) will be excluded
[ℹ]  1 iamserviceaccount (default/alb-ingress-controller) was excluded (based on the include/exclude rules)
[!]  metadata of serviceaccounts that exist in Kubernetes will be updated, as --override-existing-serviceaccounts was set
[ℹ]  no tasks
```

I am not sure whether it is created successfully or not.

I use this command `eksctl get iamserviceaccount` to verify the result but get an error response:

`Error: getting iamserviceaccounts: no output "Role1" in stack "eksctl-monitor-addon-iamserviceaccount-default-alb-ingress-controller"`

I also tried to run `kubectl get serviceaccount` but I got the error: `Error from server (NotFound): serviceaccounts "alb-ingress-controller" not found`.

Does this mean the service account failed to create? Where can I view the service account in AWS console? or where can I view the error?

Comment: --cluster arg is missed

Answer (score 5):

As per the error, it means **serviceaccount** already exists.

For getting the service account use **kubectl**

```
kubectl get serviceaccount <SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME> -n kube-system -o yaml
```

The order is, create the IAM-role, and after that – RBAC Role and binding.
Below is command in case you want to override the existing serviceaccount

```
eksctl --profile <PROFILE_NAME> \
       --region=ap-northeast-2 \
       create iamserviceaccount \
       --name alb-ingress-controller \
       --namespace kube-system \
       --override-existing-serviceaccounts \
       --approve --cluster <CLUSTER_NAME> \
       --attach-policy-arn \
       arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT_ID:policy/ALBIngressControllerIAMPolicy
```

I found this workshop [Amazon EKS Workshop](https://www.eksworkshop.com/beginner/110_irsa/iam-role-for-sa-1/) very helpful during my venture into EKS.

More information pertaining to ALB can be found [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/alb-ingress.html)

EDIT

from this error

> [ℹ]  1 existing iamserviceaccount(s) (default/alb-ingress-controller) will be excluded

It seems like the service accounts is created inside the **default** namespace.

so the command to check the serviceaccount will be

```
kubectl get serviceaccount <SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME> -n default-o yaml
```

Comment: How can I view the service account if it already exists? I searched IAM but couldn't find any service account.

Comment: I have run `kubectl get serviceaccount` but it says `Error from server (NotFound): serviceaccounts "alb-ingress-controller" not found`. It seems it doesn't exist

Comment: [Introducing fine-grained IAM roles for service accounts](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/opensource/introducing-fine-grained-iam-roles-service-accounts/) seems like the roles which are being created as part of the serviceaccount creation command are not there. Check if you have IAM permissions and cloudtrail as well for corresponding errors.

Answer (score 3):

I run into the same issue and it was due to a previous failed attempt and, in my case, was due to a previous failed attempt to create the same service account. The sa in kubernetes didn't exist after the failed attempt but the rollback in CloudFormation didn't seem to completely remove the notion of the failed as.

I have manually run the delete commons

```
eksctl delete iamserviceaccount --cluster ... --namespace ... --name ... --approve
```

Answer (score 2):

`eksctl` uses CloudFormation to create the resources so you probably will find the cause of the error there.

1. Go to CloudFormation console in AWS
2. Find the stack with the name `eksctl-[CLUSTER NAME]-addon-iamserviceaccount-default-[SERVICE ACCOUNT NAME]`, it should have the `ROLLBACK_COMPLETE` status.
3. Select the "events" tab and scroll to the first error

In my case, the cause was a missing policy that I was attaching to the role.

Answer (score 0):

works as expected, thanks @samtoddler !

---

1 Create the IAM policy for the IAM Role

```
curl -o iam_policy.json https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-load-balancer-controller/v2.3.0/docs/install/iam_policy.json
aws-vault exec Spryker-Humanetic-POC -- aws iam create-policy \
    --policy-name AWSLoadBalancerControllerIAMPolicy \
    --policy-document file://iam_policy.json
```

2 Create the IAM role and attach it to the newly created ServiceAccount

```
eksctl create iamserviceaccount \
  --cluster education-eks-7yby62S7 \
  --namespace kube-system \
  --name aws-load-balancer-controller \
  --attach-policy-arn arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT_ID:policy/AWSLoadBalancerControllerIAMPolicy \
  --approve
```

3.1 Verify # 1 that ServiceAccount lives in `--namespace kube-system`

```
kubectl get sa aws-load-balancer-controller -n kube-system -o yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  annotations:
    eks.amazonaws.com/role-arn: arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT_ID:role/eksctl-education-eks-7yby62S7-addon-iamservi-Role1-126OXTBKF3WBM
  creationTimestamp: "2021-12-12T17:38:48Z"
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: eksctl
  name: aws-load-balancer-controller
  namespace: kube-system
  resourceVersion: "686442"
  uid: 895f6f34-ab04-4bca-aeac-1b6b75766546
secrets:
- name: aws-load-balancer-controller-token-gcd5c
```

3.2 Verify #2

```
kubectl get sa aws-load-balancer-controller -n kube-system
NAME                           SECRETS   AGE
aws-load-balancer-controller   1         123m
```

Hope it will help! ‍♀️